# Button becomes unresponsive inside fixed position div

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, position

I'm using position fixed on the `#zoom-controls` so the `button` would stay at the top of the screen as I scroll. Before I added `position: fixed` to the `div`, the buttons worked, but if I add `position: fixed` the `button` becomes unresponsive.

After playing around with it on fiddlejs I found out that if you remove the `svg`, which is a sibling of the buttons div, the button works even if the div is fixed. I need the `svg` to stay.

Here is the code with the `svg` and the `position: fixed` - so it's not working:

```js
var butt = document.getElementById('zoom_in');

butt.addEventListener('click', () => {
  var body = document.getElementById('body');
  var p = document.createElement('p');
  p.textContent = 'pressed';
  body.appendChild(p);
});
```

```css
.draggable {
  cursor: move;
}

.pdf-page-canvas {
  display: block;
  margin: 5px auto;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 0;
}

.canvas_container {
  width: 100%;
  /* height: 100%; */
  z-index: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

#svg {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.js"></script>
</head>

<body id="body">
  <div id="zoom-controls" style='position:fixed'>
    <button id="zoom_in">+</button>
  </div>
  <svg id="svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 0 0" preserveAspectRatio="none"></svg>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your button container is below all of the content. Add `z-index` to it, and it will work.

```css
.draggable {
  cursor: move;
}

.pdf-page-canvas {
  display: block;
  margin: 5px auto;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 0;
}

.canvas_container {
  width: 100%;
  /* height: 100%; */
  z-index: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

#zoom-controls {
  z-index: 3;
}

#svg {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="zoom-controls" style='position:fixed'>
        <button id="zoom_in">+</button>
    </div>
    <svg id='svg' xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 0 0" preserveAspectRatio="none"></svg>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response